# How to make a full text-query on date attribute in Elastic Search

Tags: date, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a document with a date type attribute (like the following)

```
{
  "releaseDate": {
   "time": "1990-02-01T00:00:00+0000",
  }
}
```

I'm confident in doing some range query (date-math etc) so that if I'm looking for all the event in 1990, I can do the following range query

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "releaseDate.time": {
        "gte": "1990",
        "lte": "1991"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've noticed that elastic search allow making a full-text search (match) on dates

> match queries accept text/numerics/dates, analyzes them, and constructs a query. For example:
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

But I've trouble understanding how to make the right query.

for example, if I search for the following match query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "attribute.releaseDate.time": "1990"
    }
  }
}
```

Zero results are returned from ES even if the date `1990-02-01T00:00:00` exists

But if I make the following

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "attribute.releaseDate.time": "1990-02"
    }
  }
}
```

I found my event.

---

My understanding is that with the search query, ES will expand my search as `1990-01-01T00:00:00+0000` that won't match the indexed value of `1990-02-01T00:00:00+0000` while in the second query the token is the same.

This will observation will lead to my questions:

There is any way to use the following query?
 - events occurred in 1990, dates that contain the year 1990 (without a range)
 - events occurred in February of any year
 - events occurred in February the 5th of any year

But I haven't found any working example (the only thigs I've found is here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/mapping-date-field-as-multifiled-to-provide-date-query-and-full-text-search/80691)

Comment: Have you thought about just explicitly indexing the year as a separate field?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do it in this way. If you want to search by year you have to use range query and [rounding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_math_and_rounding)

For example, in your case you can use next query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "age" : {
                "gte" : "1990||/y",
                "lte" :  "1990||/y"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the year use case is clear, I've found that one idea is to use multifield